# Upgrade Magento 2.3.3 to 2.4

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento2.3.3, magento2.4

How to upgrade Magento 2.3.3 to Magento 2.4?

Comment: check here for upgrade 2.4.3-p1
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/344597/upgrade-to-magento-2-4-3/348509#348509

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First take to older version website backup and after your run direct **`magento 2.4.0`** version.

**`Magento Open Source:`**

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.0 --no-update
```

**`Magento Commerce:`**

```
composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition=2.4.0 --no-update
```

And you want to read more information check this :-

**https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/upgrade-guide/implementation/perform-upgrade.html**

**`UPDATE:-`**

I will explain more in how to update latest magento version (**2.4 at the moment**):

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.0 --no-update
composer update
```

If you are running Magento 2 commerce the command will be slightly different:

```
composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition=2.4.0 --no-update
composer update
```

**Replace 2.4** with the latest **`M2 version`**.

When it is completed, run another SSH command and upgrade the Magento database:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

After that you will want to recompile if you are in production mode:

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

**`UPDATE:- 15-AUG-2022`**

If you want to upgrade Magento to the most recent version, such as 2.4.4, then follow the below setup.

First, you need to setup PHP version 8.1 for Magento 2.4.4. Then you can run below command.

**`Magento Open Source:`**

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.4 --no-update
composer update
```

**`Magento Commerce:`**

```
composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition=2.4.4 --no-update
composer update
```

If you have any issues upgrading Magento, you can use a flag like below as a temporary solution.

```
composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
```

**https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/29350**

You’ve successfully performed a Magento 2 upgrade! Now go to the frontend and backend and check everything.

Comment: a quick note you might have to set the memory limit in your php-cli to be higher than the default. Also, --no-dev on the composer update limits the memory use as well

Comment: What do you do about php version? Some of the plugins don't want to update because of php 7.2, but changing to 7.4 creates new errors

Comment: PHP 7.3 during the upgrade then switch to php 7.4. Also install Elastic search. Not sure what else needs to change

Answer (score 4):

In addition to above response which is fully correct, you can find this guide that I wrote and give all instructions plus a few more tricks:
[here](https://medium.com/@vincentteyssier/upgrade-to-magento-2-4-7b13b4c260e7)

If you have MariaDB you will need to upgrade it, which is not straightforward but explained in that article.
Also if you were not running with Elasticsearch as your default search engine you will need to install it and configure magento to do it.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, we need to prepare for upgrade our site.

You have configure your server that works with php 7.4 and elasticsearch.
You should read system requirement official document. [Magento 2 System requirement official link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html)

Check your PHP version, it should be **7.4**

```
php -v
```

you have configured your server that works with **Elasticsearch 7.9.x**. As per the release notes of **Magento 2.4.3**, is recommended to use **Elasticsearch 7.9.x.**
You can apply the below-given command to verify your version of Elasticsearch

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200'
```

You need to require composer version 2. Check your composer version using below command

```
composer -v
```

if composer version is 1 then you should upgrade using below command

```
composer self-update --2
```

Now backup your database as well as code.

**Upgrade Magento Version from 2.3.X to 2.4.3**

1. Enable maintenance mode if you are performing on live site

   ```
   php bin/magento maintenance:enable
   ```
2. Grab backup composer.json using the below command

   ```
   cp composer.json composer.json.bak
   ```
3. Run the below command to update the composer.json file

   **For Magento Open Source, run command:**

   ```
   composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.3 --no-update
   ```

   **For Magento Commerce, run the command:**

   ```
   composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition=2.4.3 --no-update
   ```

4: Run the following command

```
composer update
```

It will take some time to get completed.

After you are done with the above steps fire below given commands.

5. Clear cache and regenerate code.

   ```
   php bin/magento cache:clean

   rm -rf var/cache/*

   rm -rf var/page_cache/*

   rm -rf generated/code/*

   php bin/magento setup:upgrade

   php bin/magento setup:di:compile

   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
   ```
6. Run this command in production mode:

   ```
   php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
   ```
7. At last don’t forget to disable maintenance mode

   ```
   php bin/magento maintenance:disable
   ```

That’s it you are upgraded to Magento 2.4.3