# how can i update magento 2.2.5 to 2.4.0 without data loss and bug?

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento-2.2.5, version

> Currently my website running on Magento 2.2.5.
>
> I want to upgrade it with current version 2.4.0.
>
> Please anyone suggests me how can I update it without getting any
> issues.
>
> wihtout lossing customized option in my Magento 2.2.5

Comment: first all backup your database and magento file. after try this following way :- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/319194/85907

Comment: Thank you Mohit Patel

Answer (score 1):

Before start magento upgrade take full backup of site then you need to check magento system requirements as per the version which link is given below and update first if required **Like :-** (php, composer, mysql, elastic search) version etc then start work on it.

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/system-requirements.html

You can upgrade magento version using command line for that you need to follow some steps which i have given below.

1. First Enable maintenance mode using a command.
   ==> **php bin/magento maintenance:enable**
2. Take backup of you composer.json file using command.
   ==> **cp composer.json composer.json.bak**
3. Update composer.json file
   ==> **composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.0 --no-update**
4. Composer update
   ==> **composer update**
5. Please run below commands one by one.
   **php bin/magento cache:clean**
   **rm -rf var/cache/***

   **rm -rf var/page_cache/***

   **rm -rf generated/code/***

   **php bin/magento setup:upgrade**

   **php bin/magento setup:di:compile**

   **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f**
6. Disable Maintainance Mode.
   ==> **php bin/magento maintenance:disable**