# Upgrade to magento 2.4.3

Tags: magento2.4, composer, magento2.4.3

I'm trying to upgrade Magento 2.4.2 to the latest release of Magento 2.4.3
How can I do this with the composer?

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html

Answer (score 8):

For community edition

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.3 --no-update
```

For enterprise edition

```
composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition=2.4.3 --no-update
composer require magento/magento-cloud-metapackage=2.4.3 --no-update
```

=========Then fire below command==========

```
composer update
rm -rf var/di var/cache/ var/page_cache/ generated/code/
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
PHP bin/magento c:f

After upgrade, check your Magento version with the following command:
```

> php bin/magento --version

Comment: i think these are the right removes for magento opensource
rm -rf var/cache/*
rm -rf var/page_cache/*
rm -rf generated/code/*

Comment: yes @eima you are absolutely right, i have update answer, thank you

Answer (score 4):

```
1. change php version to 7.4
2. php bin/magento maintenance:enable
3. COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1  composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.3-p1 --no-update
```

```
4. open composer.json and remove amazon pay by adding it it under "replace" (only if you do not need and already installed)
     "require": {
                [...]
            },
            "replace": {
                "amzn/amazon-pay-sdk-php": "*",
                "amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-with-amazon-core-module": "*",
                "amzn/login-with-amazon-module": "*",
                "amzn/amazon-pay-module": "*",
                "amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-magento-2-module": "*"
            },
            "config": {
                [...]
```

5. open composer.json and replace content of "require-dev"

```
    "require-dev": {
        "allure-framework/allure-phpunit": "~1.4",
        "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": "^0.7.0",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.18.1",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "magento/magento-coding-standard": "*",
        "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "^3.0",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "~2.7.1",
        "phpcompatibility/php-compatibility": "^9.3",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "^2.8.0",
        "phpstan/phpstan": "^0.12.77",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "^6.0.3",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "~3.5.4",
        "symfony/finder": "^5.2"
    },
```

```
6. COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer update
7. redis-clis FLUSHALL
8. php bin/magento c:f
9. php bin/magento module:disable {Magento_Elasticsearch,Magento_InventoryElasticsearch,Magento_Elasticsearch6,Magento_Elasticsearch7}
10. php bin/magento setup:upgrade
11. php bin/magento module:enable {Magento_Elasticsearch,Magento_InventoryElasticsearch,Magento_Elasticsearch6,Magento_Elasticsearch7}
12. php bin/magento c:f
13. php bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

now login to admin -> configuration -> catalog and configure elastic search.

Comment: composer update takes too much time and there is not response, approx. how much time have to wait for it ?

Comment: usually it take up to 30min or sometimes more than 1 hour. keep wait until it start upgrade process and press enter in SSH after every 5-10min. so it will not timeout

Answer (score 3):

Run the below commands :

> composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3 --no-update

> composer update

Comment: composer update gives blank with no any result, its been around 1hr+, how much it should take ?

Comment: Check any log file generate or something. Generally it can't take this much of time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the above answers will help, but...

no one mentioned --use-default-magento-values during updating, it will help the composer to update Magento composer dependencies in the `composer.json` file.

I'd recommend using the following command

`composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.3-p1 --no-update --use-default-magento-values`

And check your composer file, If you are okay with `composer.json` file changes, so run `composer update` command, Otherwise, you need to run the following command:

`composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.3-p1 --no-update --interactive-magento-conflicts` to interact with the magento changes provided then run `composer update` command.

I hope this answer may help someone to upgrade Magento to the current latest stable version.

**-- Update --**

Magenot updated the documentation for this commands like the following:
Choose one of the following composer commands based on the PHP version, and run the command to upgrade your instance.

For 7.3 or higher:

`composer require-commerce magento/<product> <version> --no-update [--interactive-root-conflicts] [--force-root-updates] [--help]`

For PHP 7.2 or lower:

`composer require magento/<product> <version> --no-update [--interactive-magento-conflicts] [--use-default-magento-values] [--help]`

Answer (score 0):

Enable Maintenace mode

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
```

Backup composer.json file

```
cp composer.json composer.json.bak
```

Update composer.json file with latest version

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.3 --no-update
```

If you get an error related to **allure-framework/allure-phpunit** and **phpunit/phpunit** package, change the version of those two packages in the composer.json file from the vanilla 2.4.3 version and run the above command again.

Update packages

```
composer update
```

This command will take some time to finish.

Clear cache and regenerate code.

```
php bin/magento cache:clean

rm -rf var/cache/*

rm -rf var/page_cache/*

rm -rf generated/code/*

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Disable maintenance mode

```
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

For more information follow this [step by step upgrade guide](https://www.codextblog.com/magento-2/how-to-upgrade-magento-version-from-2-4-0-to-2-4-3-possible-upgrade-issues-explained/).