# Laminas compile error at update to 2.4.3

Tags: magento2.4, composer, setup-di-compile

I was updating Magento Community from 2.4.2 to 2.4.3 and get this error at compile on 55%:

`Deprecated Functionality: Class Laminas\Hydrator\Reflection is deprecated, please use Laminas\Hydrator\ReflectionHydrator instead in /pathToMagento/web/vendor/laminas/laminas-hydrator/src/Reflection.php on line 17`

Any suggustions on this?

- PHP: 7.4.22
- Composer:  2.1.5

PS: Installing with Composer version 1 end up with the same error.

Comment: Magento 2 does not support php5.4. If you have that version of PHP you should update it.

Comment: Got PHP 7.4 on Server, not 5.4 have edited it later.

Comment: @Alisinasyon show us the full output of the error. It will point to the file that is using that depreciated class.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/344597/upgrade-to-magento-2-4-3/348509#348509
check here

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `laminas/laminas-hydrator` has been removed from 2.4.3. It was there in 2.4.2.

1. Upgrade the PHP version to 7.4
2. `composer require laminas/laminas-hydrator -vvv` then execute compile commands again.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/release-notes/open-source-2-4-3.html#platform-enhancements

Comment: Still get same error:

```Compilation was started.
Area configuration aggregation... 5/9 [===============>------------]  55% 1 min 380.0 MiB
In ErrorHandler.php line 61:

  User Deprecated Functionality: Class Laminas\Hydrator\Reflection is deprecated, please use Laminas\Hydrator\ReflectionHydrator instead in /var/www/clients/client1/web8/web/vendor/laminas/laminas-hydrator/src/Reflection.php on line 1
  7


setup:di:compile
```

Comment: can you see folder `laminas-hydrator` in `vendor/laminas`?

Comment: Yes, there is the direcotry