# Upgrade from 2.4.2 to 2.4.3 - I don't know how to resolve these dependencies

Tags: magento2.4, magento-community, magento-upgrade

I am looking to upgrade my Magento Store from 2.4.2 to 2.4.3. When I enter the command "composer update" I get the below response.

```
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.3].
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 1.1.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.0.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.0.3 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.0.4 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 1.1.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.0.5 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.0.6 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 1.1.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.0.7 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.0.8 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 1.1.3 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.1.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.1.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 1.1.4 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.2.0 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.2.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 1.1.5 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.2.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.2.3 (conflict analysis result)
    - csharpru/vault-php 3.5.3 requires cache/cache ^0.4.0 -> satisfiable by cache/cache[0.4.0].
    - magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 3.1.0 requires csharpru/vault-php ~3.5.3 -> satisfiable by csharpru/vault-php[3.5.3].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3 requires magento/module-aws-s3 100.4.1 -> satisfiable by magento/module-aws-s3[100.4.1].
    - Root composer.json requires magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 3.1.0 -> satisfiable by magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework[3.1.0].
    - cache/cache 0.4.0 requires league/flysystem ^1.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.0.0, ..., 1.1.5].
    - You can only install one version of a package, so only one of these can be installed: league/flysystem[1.0.0, ..., 1.1.5, 2.0.0, ..., 2.2.3].
    - magento/module-aws-s3 100.4.1 requires league/flysystem ^2.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[2.0.0, ..., 2.2.3].
    - Conclusion: don't install league/flysystem 2.0.1 (conflict analysis result)
```

My reading of this is I have 2 modules that require a different versions of league/flysystem

- cache/cache 0.4.0 requires league/flysystem 1.X
- magento/module-aws-s3 100.4.1 requires league/flysystem 2.X

How do I resolve this?

My composer.json file is here:

```
{
    "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "require": {
        "magento/composer-dependency-version-audit-plugin": "~0.1",
        "magento/composer-root-update-plugin": "~1.1",
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.4.3",
        "tnw/module-stripe": "^2.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.18.1",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "3.1.0",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "2.5.2",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.5.0",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "~3.0.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.3.1",
        "symfony/finder": "^5.2"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "gene/bluefoot": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": [
                "app/code/",
                "generated/code/"
            ]
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ],
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "**/dev/**",
            "**/update/**",
            "**/Test/**"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
        }
    },
    "version": "2.3.0",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "repositories": {
        "0": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        },
        "magesycho-magento2-custom-shipping": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "git@github.com:MagePsycho/magento2-custom-shipping.git"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    }
}
```

Comment: I am also face the same issue like this one when install fresh magneto243

Comment: I have the same issue. 2.4.2 to 2.4.3. I am working on ir right now. When I have a solution I will post an  answer.

Comment: Please refer:- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/344674/43587 it will help you

Comment: Please refer below link it will help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/344674/43587

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/344597/upgrade-to-magento-2-4-3/348509#348509

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In composer.json try to change version of 'magento2-functional-testing-framework':

from
`magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "3.1.0`

to `magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework": "3.*`

then `composer update`

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by downloading the Magento 2.4.3 release as a zip download from the Magento site, and opening up the composer.json file. I then copied the programs in the  "require-dev": section to the composer.json file in my Magento, and then Magento would upgrade.

Answer (score -1):

Try

composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.3 --no-update --use-default-magento-values

--use-default-magento-values this will update the composer json as per the default magento values

then,

composer update

Comment: This outputs this - [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]
  The "--use-default-magento-values" option does not exist.