# Upgrade from Magento commerce version from 2.4.2 to 2.4.3

Tags: magento2, magento-upgrade, magento2.4.3, magento-commerce

I am trying to update Magento commerce from Magento2.4.2 to magento2.4.3 and I am getting error while run below command:-
**composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition=2.4.3 --no-update**

and I am getting below error:-

**[InvalidArgumentException]
Could not find a matching version of package magento/product-enterprise-edition. Check the package spelling, your version constraint and that the package is available in a stability which matches your minim
um-stability (dev).**

Can anybody please help me asap.

Comment: Check the license

Comment: update the composer.json file manually with required version, also comment our the vendor folder and run the composer update

Comment: Please refer to the below link. it maybe helps you https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/344674/43587

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you do not have access to download enterprize ediition. Add the access key and secret in auth.json in docroot.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the below link. it maybe helps you
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/344674/43587