# Magento 2 : Getting Error while upgrade magento from 2.2.6 to latest version 2.4.3

Tags: magento2, upgrade, composer, magento2.2.6, magento2.4.3

I am try to upgrade magento version from 2.2.6 to 2.4.3 using composer method.

When try to that, I face following error which attached in screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrDVG.png,

please help..

Comment: You have a problem with the php version you use to run the update: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66519169/call-to-undefined-function-str-contains-php

Comment: check below answer for complete upgrade requirements
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/344597/upgrade-to-magento-2-4-3/348509#348509

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove **vendor** directory and then run **composer update** command.

Comment: Thank You So Much Kishan Savaliya For the best solution but before removing vendor & composer update, we need to edit composer.json file and in this we need to add required dependency modules from M2.4.3 in require-dev section.

Comment: Yes true, that is required. But in above screenshot your composer was skipping module from downloading. :) Great this solution works for you.

Comment: Yes Thank You So Much Brother for Great Solution !!!