# Magento 2 Upgrade Issue from 2.3.6 to 2.4.4

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento-upgrade, magento2.4.4, magento2.3.6

I am trying to upgrade **Magento** from **2.3.6 to 2.44** using this link https://magecomp.com/blog/upgrade-magento-version-from-2-3-to-2-4/, Now issue is that **Magento 2.4.4. requires PHP 7.4** and **Magento 2.3.6 works on PHP 7.3**. I have installed **PHP 7.4** before upgrading but when I run the **composer update** command. I face this issue:

```
**- sw/theme-conserva 1.0.0 requires php ~7.2.0||~7.3.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.30) does not satisfy that requirement.**
```

Any Solution?

Comment: Since Magento *2.4.4* requires *PHP 8.1*. You can use flag `--ignore-platform-reqs` for composer to ignore this message, but I suggest to review installed extension and remove/replace outdated (not compatible)

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear that your theme "conserva" is not compatible with PHP 7.4. So these are the steps to resolve the issue:

1. Upgrade the code of that theme to be PHP 7.4 compatible
2. Update the theme's `composer.json` file to reflect the new compatibility
3. Continue your upgrade

Comment: Hey Thanks, that issue is resolved but now facing a new error. Please take a look.
- magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.3.6-p1 requires php ~7.1.3||~7.2.0||~7.3.0 -> your PHP version (7.4.30) does not satisfy that requirement.

Comment: @RalphRhodes That is the exact same problem, with the exact same step to resolve.

Comment: No, that's a theme but I can't find any file with the same name in magento folder. I tried

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming `sw/theme-conserva` is your theme name. As a result, I recommend installing your theme in the most recent version of `Magento 2.4.4`, or you can remove `sw/theme-conserva` from your `composer.json` file and re-run the `composer update` command.

To upgrade Magento from a lower version to a higher version, you need to setup PHP version 8.1 for Magento 2.4.4.

If you want to upgrade Magento without any issues, you can use a flag like below.

```
composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Also, for my full answer, check the link.

**https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/319194/85907**

**https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/29350**

**`THANKS.`**

Comment: - magento/magento-cloud-metapackage 2.3.6 requires magento/product-enterprise-edition >=2.3.6 <2.3.7 -> satisfiable by magento/product-enterprise-edition[2.3.6-p1, 2.3.6] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - magento/magento-cloud-metapackage 2.3.6 requires magento/product-enterprise-edition >=2.3.6 <2.3.7 -> satisfiable by magento/product-enterprise-edition[2.3.6-p1, 2.3.6] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

Comment: - Installation request for magento/magento-cloud-metapackage >=2.3.6 <2.3.7 -> satisfiable by magento/magento-cloud-metapackage[2.3.6].

Comment: I am getting above errors even after using the same methods of ignore plateform

Comment: check this link. https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/29350